# updating other row values with the same row id values with auto-incrementing numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows, I want to automatically increase the SIRANO value according to the rows with the same MF_ID value in this table.

| SIRANO | MF_ID |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 30 |
| NULL | 30 |
| NULL | 30 |
| NULL | 31 |
| NULL | 31 |
| NULL | 32 |

must be:

| SIRANO | MF_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 1 | 32 |

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
update A 
set SIRANO = (case when A.MF_ID=B.MF_ID then @counter+1
                           else 0
                           end)
FROM MYTABLE_0002 a 
INNER JOIN MYTABLE_0002 b
on a.MF_ID = b.MF_ID
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `UPDATE`able CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER` achieve this?

Comment: I want it to do this automatically in a large table, the query I wrote did not provide this :(

Comment: you can use this is query,first you must made a small query with limited result for example "where MF_ID=@"
;With UpdateData  As
(
SELECT MF_ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by MF_ID  ORDER BY MF_ID DESC) AS RN,SIRANO
FROM T
)
UPDATE T SET SIRANO = RN
FROM UpdateData T